# write.csv() in dplyr chain

Tags: r, csv, file-io, dplyr

I've come across this problem before, but just wrote the export function outside of the chain.  Is there a way to include a `write.csv` statement within a `dplyr` chain?

```
library(dplyr)

data_set %>%
filter(Date == Sys.Date() - 1 | Date == Sys.Date()) %>%
write.csv('data_set_twodays.csv', row.names = F) %>%
filter(Date = Sys.Date()) %>%
write.csv('data_set_today.csv', row.names = F)
NULL
```

Comment: I assume the chain takes the return value of each "link" and passes it to the next.  Since there is no return from `write.csv` this probably won't work.  You could wrap `write.csv` and make sure to return the data... then maybe...

Comment: please take a look at my  answer. I believe it is more useful for others who have the same need.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This appeared to work for me in version 0.2:

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4) %>% write.csv(.,file = "~/Desktop/piping.csv")
```

Comment: wow, this dplyr stuff is really beginning to look like a new language... Like unix pipes meet lisp or something.

Comment: Since the data is the first argument to `write.csv()` you don't need `.` or the explicit argument name, `file`.

Comment: @hadley Any way to make this work with `group_by`? e.g.
`df %>% group_by(SomeGroup) %>% write.csv(paste0(SomeGroup, ".csv"))`

Comment: Not a `dplyr` answer, but I remembered that `split` exists after posting. Assuming you didn't need the SomeGroup column in the result: `dl = split(df, df$SomeGroup); for (somegroup in dl) {write.csv(select(somegroup, -Somegroup), paste0(first(somegroup$Somegroup), ".csv"))`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233405 for using `group_by` followed by `do` function call to export data frame.

Comment: The answer will not work mid-pipe which was what the OP asked for. See @kmace's answer which does work mid-pipe.

Answer (score 11):

The T pipe is what you're looking for:

`%T>%` will run the function, but pass the input as output

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data_set %>%
filter(Date == Sys.Date() - 1 | Date == Sys.Date()) %T>%
write.csv('data_set_twodays.csv', row.names = F) %>%
filter(Date = Sys.Date()) %T>%
write.csv('data_set_today.csv', row.names = F)
```

people often use it to plot an intermediate without breaking their pipes!

From the docs:

```
rnorm(200) %>%
matrix(ncol = 2) %T>%
plot %>% # plot usually does not return anything. 
colSums
```