# How can I write dplyr groups to separate files?

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, readr

I'm trying to create separate .csv files for each group in a data frame grouped with dplyr's group_by function.  So far I have something like

```
by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
do(by_cyl, write_csv(., "test.csv"))
```

As expected, this writes a single .csv file with only the data from the last group.  How can I modify this to write multiple .csv files, each with filenames that include cyl?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wrap the csv write process in a custom function as follows. Note that the function has to return
    a `data.frame` else it returns an error `Error: Results are not data frames at positions`

This will return 3 csv files named "mtcars_cyl_4.csv","mtcars_cyl_6.csv" and "mtcars_cyl_8.csv"

```
customFun  = function(DF) {
write.csv(DF,paste0("mtcars_cyl_",unique(DF$cyl),".csv"))
return(DF)
}

mtcars %>% 
group_by(cyl) %>% 
do(customFun(.))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  As an aside - in my actual case I was grouping by two variables; turns out the order by which you group them is really important.  For the example, "cyl" would have to be the first grouping for this to work.

Comment: Beautiful function wrapper! Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

With `dplyr_0.8.0` this can be done with `group_by` and `group_walk`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   group_walk(~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y$cyl, "test.csv")))
```

Comment: I had no idea this function existed, thanks for your answer!

Comment: This is so much easier now! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The following works (you can skip the custom function)

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>%
  do(write_csv(., paste0(unique(.$cyl), "test.csv")))
```

Comment: I get this "Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" while the answer by @OdeToMyFiddle works.

Answer (score 4):

If you were willing to use data.table there is a slightly less clunky way of doing it.

```
require(data.table)
# Because this is a built in table we have to make a copy first
mtcars <- mtcars 
setDT(mtcars) # convert the data into a data.table

mtcars[, write.csv(.SD, paste0("mtcars_cyl_", .BY, ".csv")), by = cyl]
```

Note that the resulting table will not have a column for cyl (which would be redundant since it is stored in the file name, but maybe you want to leave it in for other reasons).

If you want cyl to be included in the output as a column you can use

```
mtcars[, write.csv(c(.BY,.SD), paste0("mtcars_cyl_", .BY, ".csv")), by=cyl]
```

Comment: You get an error if you convert one of the built in tables to a data.table without copying it first. Here's the error you get "Error in setDT(mtcars) :
  Can not convert 'mtcars' to data.table by reference because binding is locked. It is very likely that 'mtcars' resides within a package (or an environment) that is locked to prevent modifying its variable bindings. Try copying the object to your current environment, ex: var <- copy(var) and then using setDT again."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rich.

Comment: @RobDonnelly , If you really want to improve the speed of your code, replace `write.csv` with `fwrite`, which is the native `data.table` way of writing a `.csv`. It is super fast as it works in parallel.

Comment: @RobDonnelly Is there a way to use `fwrite()` instead of using `write.csv()` in your code? the former one is way faster when applied to large datasets.