# Write files for several column filter

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Given a data.frame and a set of columns, I'd like to write a csv file (or text file in general)
for each column containing but containing information for all columns, however rows filtered based on the respective column.

For example, say I'd like to save a file for each, **Sepal.Width** and **Sepal.Length** containing the **top 5** rows for each respectively:

```r
top_n(iris, 5, Sepal.Width) 
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 2          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
# 3          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
# 4          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
# 5          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
# 6          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
# this should go in top5_Sepal.Width.csv
top_n(iris, 5, Sepal.Length)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
# 2          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
# 3          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
# 4          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
# 5          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
# this should go in top5_Sepal.Length.csv
```

I've tried something like below, however I don't know to write the `mywrite` function i.e. how access the whole data.frame for filtering (`.x` only contains the column)

```r
myvars <- c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")
tmp <- iris %>%
  map_at(myvars, ~mywrite(.x))
```

Alternatively, `purrr:map2` allows to track names, but doesn't come in an `_at`flavour (I guess filtering can be done in `mywrite` then..
However, again no access to the whole iris data.frame:

```r
tmp <- iris %>%
  map2(., colnames(iris), ~mywrite(.x, .y))
```

As a third option, I think there is the option to loop over the column names, possibly using tidy evaluation i.e. `mycol <- sym(myvars[i])` and `!!mycol` , but wanted to refrain from for loops ideally.

Note, this is a somewhat silly toy example which only serves to illustrate the issue.

Note2, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807068/6905116) answer is similar but based on groups within a column rather than individual columns:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map` with non-standard evaluation to get top 5 values for each `myvars`

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(myvars, ~top_n(iris, 5, !!sym(.x)))

#[[1]]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#2          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
#3          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
#4          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
#5          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
#6          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa

#[[2]]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#2          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#3          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#4          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#5          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica
```

If you want to write each part to csv, you can extend the pipe to

```
map(myvars, ~top_n(iris, 5, !!sym(.x)) %>% write.csv(paste0("top5_", .x, ".csv")))
```

Comment: This is very neat! Haven't thought to use non-standard evaluation that way, thanks for that! The only thing that could be improved to make it more generic is to use it within a pipe, i.e. starting 'iris %>% map(...`, without referring to `iris` thereafter, do you think this is possible?

Comment: @SebastianMüller What do you mean by generic? I think the above solution could be applied to any dataframe as well? The issue starting with `iris %>%` is, it will not return you all other columns. You can try `iris %>%
  select(myvars) %>%
  map(~top_n(tibble(.x), 5))`

Comment: With generic I was referring to the `iris %>%....` solution. And yes, in this particular solution, `.x` only contains the subsetted column, so I suppose there is no variable besides `.x` that would contain the passed on data.frame?

Comment: So `map` in the above answer operates on each of `myvars` variable when we do `iris %>% map` it operates on every column in `iris`.

Comment: I guess that at this point this solution can't be achieved with `iris %>% ...` approach. But your answer is good enough anyway, thanks!