# R function to split .csv data into multiple .csv data based on same row

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

I have .csv data with large number of row. is there any function to split that in to multiple .csv based on same row (example based on same "location" column)? thank you

[image]

I tried to split my one .csv data in to several .csv data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to split the data into a list of data frame, then `lapply` to write them to new csvs, e.g.

```
data<-read.csv("filename.csv")
datalist<-split(data,data$location)
lapply(datalist, function(dat){
write.csv(dat,paste0("data",dat$location[1],".csv"))
})
```

Comment: A tidyverse solution is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807068/9076343